# How to make pagination in Laravel when the URL length exceeds its limit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working on a project with Laravel 5.2 
I have hidden ID values and I want to search the ID from the database and later I will sort it in descending order.
I wrote this code.

Controller

```
$jsonObject =json_decode(request('membersdata'));
$member = (new Membermasternewdata)->newQuery();
$members=$member->whereIn('id', $jsonObject)->latest();
$members=$members->paginate(50);
```

View 
The HTML page

```
{{$members->appends(request()->except('page'))->links()}}
```

My URL example http://localhost:8000/ascendingregistrationdate?_token=ktlNHgx9PLNCOQL0CE1YZT2AzmWpJeXexqOduy8F&membersdata=%5B199%2C284%2C344%2C355%2C381%2C461%2C488%2C576%2C601%2C652%2C747%2C825%2C849%2C878%2C883%2C912%2C913%2C915%2C972%2C1004%2C1071%2C1310%2C1501%2C1534%2C1585%2C1610%2C1677%2C1854%2C1923%2C1935%2C2163%2C2301%2C2302%2C2326%2C2339%2C2717%2C2773%2C3052%2C3361%2C3446%2C3683%2C3848%2C3853%2C3914%2C4114%2C4244%2C4311%2C4357%2C4389%2C4881%2C5312%2C5322%5D&page=2

I got a problem with pagination. For around 400 records, the pagination works.  But If I have many records, pagination doesn't work as the URL length exceed its limit. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a sidenote, Laravel 5.2 has been EOL for almost a year now, please consider updating to at least 5.5: https://endoflife.software/programming-languages/frameworks/laravel

Comment: @Loek , that is right. Unfortunately, the client-server PHP version is a bit old. That is why I use Laravel 5.2 for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a GET request for the search, why don't you switch to using POST instead. That way, the `memberdata` array can be passed as POST data, which can have larger limits for the data (depending on your PHP config, this would be 2+ MB.

The `memberdata` in the URL is what's causing the URL to exceed the max limit, so you need to remove that from the URL.